# Does java.io.Process guarantee the output to remain even if the subprocess has exited?

Tags: java, process, io, stream, buffer

If proc has exited, where are the output strings stored?

Internal buffer?

How if the internal buffer is too small to contain the huge strings?

Can we be guaranteed to get the strings without loss?

```
package Hello;

import java.io.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String line = null;

        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new 
                ProcessBuilder("command_to_output_huge_strings");

            Process proc = pb.start();
            proc.waitFor();
            //
            // Now proc may have finished its huge output and exited.
            //   

            // Now we want to get the huge strings proc outputed.
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by lossless??

Comment: I mean the Java process can get the whole output of its subprocess even if the subprocess has exited.

Comment: **Don't** embed your question in the code. Put it out in the text where everybody can see it.

Comment: That's the idea of running sub process. You might wanna take a look at Process.getInputStream() methods to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no buffering in `Process.getInputStream().`
2. There may be buffering in the process itself.
3. The process can't exit until it has flushed its buffers.
4. You are calling `Process.waitFor()` and then trying to read its output.
5. Your question therefore doesn't make sense, and your code is back to front. You should read all the process's output and *then* call `waitFor().`